# XSLT to change namespace in element

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to change the namespace of an element attribute using the below xsl code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='2.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:ns2="http://www.ean-ucc.org/schemas/1.3.1/eanucc"> 
    <xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

    <!-- copy everything into the output -->
    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="IRenvelope">
        <IRL xmlns:xsd="http://www.xx.com">
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
        </IRL>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml message i use for testing is:

```
<GMessage xmlns="http://www.giffgaff.uk/CM/envelope">
<EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <body>
    <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap">
            <Keys>
                <Key Type="TaxOfficeNumber">635</Key>
            </Keys>
        </IRenvelope>
   </body>
 </GMessage>
```

I couldnt make it work and the namespace is not changing but provinding the same result. any help please?

The output xml to be as follows:

```
     <GMessage xmlns="http://www.giffgaff.uk/CM/envelope">
         <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
           <body>
             <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.xx.com">
               <Keys>
                  <Key Type="TaxOfficeNumber">635</Key>
                </Keys>
               </IRenvelope>
            </body>
       </GMessage>
```

Comment: In the input XML the element, `IRenvelope`, falls under the namespace `http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap`. But your XSLT matches the element `IRenvelope` without this namespace. Also, the element you are creating, `IRL` falls under empty namespace. If you want it to fall under `http://www.xx.com` the element name should have the `xsd` prefix(`xsd:IRL`).

Comment: thkx for your feedback. what shuld i do for IRenvelope to fall under the namesace and provide me the output as attached? pls any inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below XSLT will help you to get the desired results:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.xx.com"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns"> 
    <xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

    <!-- copy everything into the output -->
    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*, node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to match ns:IRenvelope element and creating a new element -->
    <xsl:template match="ns:IRenvelope">
        <xsl:element name="IRL" namespace="http://www.xx.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to change the namespace 
         of the elements  
         from "http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap" 
         to "http://www.xx.com" -->
    <xsl:template match="ns:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.xx.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, the last two templates match the `ns:IRenvelope` and all the elements with namespace `http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap`, respectively. Using the `xsl:element` and its namespace attribute, we can create the new elements with desired namespace.

You can also declare the desired namespaces with prefixes and create elements as below:

```
<xsd:IRL xmlns:xsd="http://www.xx.com">
    ...
</xsd:IRL>
```

For XSLT-1.0:

Just replace the `,`(comma) to use a `|`(pipe) in apply-templates as using comma to sequence the action is supported in 2.0:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
```

Comment: hi lingamurthy, thks. i tried this xslt but it didnt help much. same result as the original xml.

Comment: my apologise, I tried to test via altova xml spy but could not get it working there :(

Comment: Hi - this works perfectly with altova but with SAP my system supports version 1.0 only and not 2.0. Can you help me with the code for compatible version 1.0?