# XSLT To change namespace - Version Compatibility

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Original post:

[XSLT to change namespace in element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286987/xslt-to-change-namespace-in-element/42287010?noredirect=1#comment71746021_42287010)

Its regarding my earlier post with xslt program to replace a namespace. I had the question answered but when testing with my system it shows error as the application system i work support version 1.0

Please Need some help to make the code compatibly with version 1.0. Below is the xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.xx.com"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns"> 

    <xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

    <!-- copy everything into the output -->
    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*, node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to match ns:IRenvelope element and creating a new element -->
    <xsl:template match="ns:IRenvelope">
        <xsl:element name="IRL" namespace="http://www.xx.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 
        template to change the namespace 
        of the elements  
        from "http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap" 
        to "http://www.xx.com" 
    -->

    <xsl:template match="ns:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.xx.com">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my xml message would be:

```
<GMessage xmlns="http://www.giffgaff.uk/CM/envelope">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
    <body>
        <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.mnv.com/elc/sap">
            <Keys>
                <Key Type="TaxOfficeNumber">635</Key>
            </Keys>
        </IRenvelope>
    </body>
</GMessage>
```

expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GMessage xmlns="http://www.giffgaff.uk/CM/envelope">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
    <body>
        <IRL xmlns="http://www.xx.com">
            <Keys>
                <Key Type="TaxOfficeNumber">635</Key>
            </Keys>
        </IRL>
    </body>
</GMessage>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies solely with these lines...

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select='@*, node()'/>
```

This syntax is not valid in XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 2.0, the comma is used to build a "sequence".

However, you can simply replace occurrences of that line with this instead, which will work in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
```

The pipe character is a union operator to join node sets.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.....Please can you help on how to have the namespace as : <IRL xmlns:ne="http://www.xx.com"> in the xml?

Comment: It's probably best you ask a new question, as I am not quite sure what the problem is. Thanks.